# How to align text in different Text widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I using `Text('00:47')`, the colon in the middle can be centered vertically with the number, as shown below:

[image]

But when I combine three  `Text` widgets, the colon loses its alignment.

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text('00'),
    Text(':'),
    Text('47'),
  ],
)
```

[image]

How can I make the colon and number vertically centered?

Comment: Did you try crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlighnment.center ?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya, CrossAxisAxisAlignment's default is CrossAxisAlignment.center.

Comment: and are you styling your text, else you can do something like Text("00" + " : " + "47")

Comment: agreed, what is the reason for using 3 different `Text` widgets?

Comment: Actually, I used `Text('$minutes:$seconds')`. But when minutes and seconds change, the colon not always in the middle of the screen, it will moves left or right. @pskink

Comment: you can use center wigdet

Comment: and how will it help if you have 3 `Text`s? maybe you should use [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces)?

Comment: It's the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936651/6005699

Comment: so the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936541/2252830) is: `"Use a monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or non-proportional font"`

Comment: Strangely enough, I can reproduce this vertical shift of semicolon on iOS only. Web and Android with default fonts, both align semicolon on the bottom in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
      Text('00'),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: Text(':'),
      ),
      Text('47'),
    ],
  )
```